# How can I use a table in R for names.arg

Tags: r, plot

I have a table in R that I am using to make a barplot:

```
86 17  482 424  C
87 18  600 426  T
88 11  279 427  Q
89 X   399 436  B
```

I can make the plot with `barplot(table$V3`) but how do I use the values in V4 as the names for each V3 entry?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible answer, show how you're making the barplot now, so that users can help correct this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  To help make a reproducible example, you can use   `reproduce(<your data>)` . Instructions are here:  http://bit.ly/SORepro   .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use

```
 barplot(DF$V3, names.arg=DF$V4)
```

where `DF` is your `data.frame`   (a `table` is something else in `R`.  If you actually mean `table`, please indicate as such)